# How do I pattern match nested list inside a struct?

Tags: elixir

Giving the example below, is there way to match **entries** is a list or a list of TodoEntry?

```
defmodule Todo do
    defstruct [:entries]

    def add_entry(%Todo{entries: _} = todo, %TodoEntry{date: {_, _, _}, title: _} = entry) do

    end 
end

defmodule TodoEntry do
    defstruct [:date, :title]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Following piece of code should just work for you:

```
defmodule TodoEntry do
    defstruct [:date, :title]
end

defmodule Todo do
  defstruct [:entries]

  def add_entry(%Todo{entries: nil} = todo, %TodoEntry{} = entry) do
    %Todo{entries: [entry]}
  end

  def add_entry(%Todo{entries: [%TodoEntry{}|_]} = todo, %TodoEntry{} = entry) do
    %Todo{entries: [entry | todo.entries]}
  end  
end
```

I assume you are expecting it to function like:

```
todo = %Todo{}

entry = %TodoEntry{date: {2,6,2016}, title: "My new Todo"}
todo = Todo.add_entry(todo,entry)

entry = %TodoEntry{date: {2,6,2017}, title: "My todo next year"}
todo = Todo.add_entry(todo,entry)

entry = %TodoEntry{date: {2,6,2026}, title: "My new todo next decade, if I cared"}
todo = Todo.add_entry(todo,entry)
```

Comment: Thanks Abhijeet. I pretty much ended up with a very similar structure after your first post yesterday. I don't know enough about Elixir yet but I feel like pattern matching complex hierarchical types could be a lot of effort. Where in strongly types languages we don't have this problem. I wonder if Elixir another mechanism to allow this with less effort.

Comment: Elixir(/Erlang) is usually excellent for pattern matching. Pattern matching complex hierarchy should also be possible using nested structure definitions. I think it's all pretty unless you bring in the lists. I never used lists in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with. Though I feel like I am putting a lot of effort just to validate the expected structure passed-in.

```
defmodule TodoEntry do
    defstruct [:date, :title]

    def create(entry) do
        %TodoEntry{date: {_, _, _}, title: _} = entry
    end
end

defmodule Todo do
    defstruct [:entries]

    def new do
        %Todo{entries: []}
    end 

    def add_entry(%Todo{entries: []} = todo, entry) do      
        entry = TodoEntry.create(entry)
        entries = update_entries(entry, todo.entries) 

        %Todo{todo | entries: entries}
    end 

    def add_entry(%Todo{entries: [_]} = todo, entry) do 
        entries = [%TodoEntry{date: {_, _, _}, title: _}] =  todo.entries
        entry   = TodoEntry.create(entry)

        entries = update_entries(entry, entries) 

        %Todo{todo | entries: entries}
    end 

    defp update_entries(entry, entries) do
        [entry | entries]
    end
```

end